# how to specify a different location for Virtual Directories in Web Setup Projects

Tags: c#, deployment, installation

I want to install my virtual directory other than the default location(c:\inetpub\wwwroot).
I want that the directory will be created in the physical path enntered by the user.

Please suggest any way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not exactly what you ask but follow the steps described in the main answer here: [Virtual Directory in Web Setup Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714309/virtual-directory-in-web-setup-project)

...and instead of changing TextBoxes to not visible keep them visible so you can capture user input.

Comment: if I add a textbox(a) dialog and take virtual directory name and physical path as input from user ,how the web setup copy the website files in that virtual directory which got created.

Answer (score 0):

Using the System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.IISVirtualRoot you can create a [Virtual direcoty through C#,](http://forums.iis.net/t/1139885.aspx)

```
 System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.IISVirtualRoot vr = new System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.IISVirtualRoot();
  string sError = "";
vr.Create("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root", physicalPath, VDName, out sError);
```